# How to select a particular list item from a list? (like the sixth or second etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an unorganized list:

```
<ul id="box">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

and for example I want the second. Can I do something like this? :

```
$("#box li").[2].click();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#box li").eq(2).click();
$("#box li:eq(2)").click();
```

**or**

```
$("#box li:nth-child(3)").click();
```

Keep in mind that [**:nth-child**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) is a CSS pseudo-class and starts counting in 1, [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [**:eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is a array index starting on 0. So `nth-child(3)` is the same element as `eq(2)`.

Might be interesting to check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHQz5/1/).

Comment: I stand corrected: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo (if you're curious about being right or wrong always check with the W3C's site, for html and CSS) =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq) or [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) here

```
$("#box li").eq(2).click();
$("#box li:eq(2)").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.eq()` function for that.

```
$('#box li').eq(2).click();
```

Note that the first index is zero, so if you wanted the second element it'd be element 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:eq()` selector, which is zero based, so the second element would be `:eq(1)`

```
$("#box li:eq(1)").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

if n is a variable, you can use

```
$('#box li:eq(' + variable + ')').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clicklist(i){

$('#box li:eq(' + i+ ')').click()
}
```

Then if you want to click 1st row  do

```
clicklist(0);
```

If you wanna 4th

```
clicklist(3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you where almost correct in your first guess. Just remove the dot.

```
$($("#box li")[2]).click(function(){
    alert('you clicked the third element');
});
```

This will work with your markup. => http://jsfiddle.net/jju9J/

You can also use the eq() function ; but the basic way make you understand better what you are doing.